# Tensor Flow using GPU Nvidia

Tags: python, tensorflow, nvidia, conv-neural-network

I'm working on a Python project using tensorflow. I would like to use GPU to reduce the time required to train the model. I have followed the steps to install Cuda Toolkit and I have added the necessary Environment Variables. I'm still getting this error:

```
2020-11-01 15:04:56.197406: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2020-11-01 15:04:58.911682: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2020-11-01 15:04:58.960424: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1716] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce RTX 2060 computeCapability: 7.5
coreClock: 1.2GHz coreCount: 30 deviceMemorySize: 6.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 312.97GiB/s
2020-11-01 15:04:58.969038: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2020-11-01 15:04:58.980867: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
2020-11-01 15:04:58.988995: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2020-11-01 15:04:59.001511: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2020-11-01 15:04:59.015870: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2020-11-01 15:04:59.022750: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_10.dll
2020-11-01 15:04:59.035897: **W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:59] Could not load dynamic library 'cudnn64_7.dll'; dlerror: cudnn64_7.dll not found
2020-11-01 15:04:59.049352: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1753] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.**
Skipping registering GPU devices...
2020-11-01 15:04:59.070732: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN)to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
```

Has anyone an idea on how to solve this problem?
Thanks

Comment: In addition to installing CUDA (proper version) you must also install cuDNN (proper version) to use tf-gpu.

Comment: I have downloaded "cuDNN Library for Windows10 (x86)" for Cuda version 10.1 that is the one I have on my pc, from the site: https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-download

Comment: You should: 1. Make sure it is the proper version expected by your tf-gpu build   2. Make sure the libraries can be found in the environment your tf-gpu is running in.

Comment: Opening the folder :"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\cuda\bin", I find the file "cudnn64_8.dll" while Tensorflow is looking for "cudnn64_7.dll"

Comment: There you go, that is the likely the problem.

Comment: I should have resolved by downloading an older version of cudnn library in particular :"https://developer.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/cudnn/secure/7.6.5.32/Production/10.1_20191031/cudnn-10.1-windows10-x64-v7.6.5.32.zip"  and I have unzipped the file to the same previous folder: "C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1".

Comment: Now at this folder : ""C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\cuda\bin" I have two files "cudnn64_7.dll" and "cudnn64_8.dll" but it's all woriking